# How to get the specific C compiler type from Python distutils?

Tags: python, c

I'd like to check the system's C compiler in Python so that I can add library links accordingly to compile my Cython code.

I understand `distutils.ccompiler.get_default_compiler()` or something like `compiler.compiler_type` would return a compiler name. But it is too coarse just like "unix", etc.

What I need is more specific information such as "gcc", "icc", "clang", etc., which are all shown as "unix" using the methods above.

One possible way to get the information is to check the system's environment variable `CC` via `os.environ["CC"]`, but it is not guaranteed that every system has `CC` defined so it is not a universal solution.

So, what should I do then? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should be able to use the **[`platform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.python_compiler)** module to get the info:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_compiler()
'GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)'
```

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like that this will return the system's default compiler, e.g. in my system, the basic GCC version located at `/usr/bin`. Is this the compiler Cython will use when `import pyximport; pyximport.install()`? A user may have some other compiler to use as the default one (e.g. specified by his/her own `CC` environment variable), how can I get that?

Comment: Often you won't get anything other than "cc" coming back from the `CC` variable in Python `distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('CC')`,  If you don't see anything set from the `disutils` command it's likely set to the default compiler that outputs from `os.system('cc -v')`, which the default should match the output of `platform`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. So my final solution is a two-step one: first check if `CC` is set, if yes, read `os.environ["CC"]`; if no, get info from `distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('CC')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `distutils` to get the actual c compiler and read its properties

```py
from distutils.ccompiler import new_compiler
from distutils.sysconfig import customize_compiler
ccompiler = new_compiler()
customize_compiler(ccompiler)

path_to_compiler = ccompiler.compiler[0]
```